# Web Essentials 2013 unused css is not working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, web-essentials

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials 2013 and when using browser link, it is not finding unused css when using both IE11 and Chrome 31.  I have tried everything I can think of and it won't show me the unused css class.  Everything else with browser link seems to be working except this function.  Does anyone have any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Run the project and make sure Browser Link is enabled. While running there is an icon on your toolbar with a round going arrow. Click the downarrow next to it and click "Start Recording (all browsers)".

Keep an eye on your Error List window where it should start showing the unused CSS. When click through your website the list should decrease as it ticks off the CSS it encounters.

Make sure that you go through all the paths of your website otherwise some CSS might be marked as unused while it actually is (jQuery addClass for example).

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM5oz_2OidI

Comment: I'm using web essential 2015.3 Browser link is working properly, but I don't have any record button under the circle arrow button, as seen in the video. What should I have to enable to show the button?